# akka.io receive line by line in 2.3

Tags: scala, tcp, akka

I'm using Akka 2.3 (since that's the version which comes with Play) and want to connect to some TCP socket. I'm aware of the `akka.io` package. However I can't see any way to process the received data as UTF-8 string **line by line** (against just receiving byte chunks).

Searching the web there are quite a few references to the experimental Pipeline API of Akka 2.2. However this API got removed in Akka again.

What I'm looking for is what is known as `readLine` in most buffer classes but for the Akka I/O Framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The replacement of the old pipelines is [Akka Streams](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0-RC3/scala.html), which provide a *streaming* TCP implementation. It is possible to add a lines parser to such stream to easily obtain a "stream of lines".

A built in line parser will be merged very soon [+str #17310: Basic framing support](https://github.com/akka/akka/pull/17446). Currently the line parser is a cookbook you can paste into your project: [Akka Streams Cookbook: Parsing lines from ByteStrings](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0-M2/scala/stream-cookbook.html#Parsing_lines_from_a_stream_of_ByteStrings).

I suggest you first read the [Working with Streaming IO](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0-RC3/scala/stream-io.html) docs and then modify the samples such that it matches your use case (by using the `parseLines` cookbook recipe).

Please note that Akka Streams are still experimental and API may change slightly.
Another important information is that they implement the [www.reactive-streams.org](http://www.reactive-streams.org/announce-1.0.0) specification, so you get back-pressure out of the box without having to manually worry about it :-)

Answer (score 1):

[Akka Stream](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0-RC3/scala.html) seems promising, however since it's still unreleased I decided to implement it myself by simply contacting all data in a buffer and waiting for the separator chars.

```
  private val separatorBytes = // like CRLF
  private var buffer = ByteString.empty
  private var nextPossibleMatch = 0

  // when receiving chunks of bytes they are appended to buffer and doParseLines is executed

  private def doParseLines(parsedLinesSoFar: Vector[String] = Vector()): Vector[String] = {
    val possibleMatchPos = buffer.indexOf(separatorBytes.head, from = nextPossibleMatch)
    if (possibleMatchPos == -1) {
      parsedLinesSoFar
    } else {
      if (possibleMatchPos + separatorBytes.size > buffer.size) {
        nextPossibleMatch = possibleMatchPos
        parsedLinesSoFar
      } else {
        if (buffer.slice(possibleMatchPos, possibleMatchPos + separatorBytes.size) == separatorBytes) {
          // Found a match
          val parsedLine = buffer.slice(0, possibleMatchPos).utf8String
          buffer = buffer.drop(possibleMatchPos + separatorBytes.size)
          nextPossibleMatch -= possibleMatchPos + separatorBytes.size
          doParseLines(parsedLinesSoFar :+ parsedLine)
        } else {
          nextPossibleMatch += 1
          doParseLines(parsedLinesSoFar)
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yup, that works as well; Small correction on releases: it is released in RC phase, the 1.0 stable version, after which it will become part of Akka is a few weeks away. It will remain experimental for at least the entire lifetime of Akka 2.4